# How to add another DataSource in prompt Query?

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to add another data source in Query prompt.

When I launch a form I open the prompt Query.

In my form `init` method I have:

```
QueryRun queryRun;

super();

queryRun = new QueryRun(TableA_ds.query());
if (! queryRun.prompt())
{
     element.close();
}

TableA_ds.query(queryRun.query());
```

In my Form data source, in `init` method, I have put this code to set my query range:

```
tableA_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(TableA)).addRange(fieldnum(TableA,FieldtableA)).value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited() );
```

I want to add another data source (another table) - TableB.
I used this code:

```
purchLine_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(TableB)).addRange(fieldnum(TableB,FieldtableB)).value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited() );
```

But when I launch a Form I view only record query range from TableA

Relation of TableA to TableB is on field `PurchId`.
I want to see two ranges. Can someone help me?
Thanks for your time.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add another datasource with:
    purchLine_ds.query().dataSourcetable(TableA).addDatasource(tablenum(TableB);
    purchLine_ds.query().dataSourcetable(TableB).relations(true)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex , for your Help,
I used this code, 
in my Form init Method :

```
query q = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource qbds, qbds2;
QueryRun queryRun;

qbds = Q.addDataSource(tableNum(TableA));
qbds.addRange(fieldnum(TableA,Field1TableA)).value(SysQuery::valueUnlimited());
qbds2 = qbds.addDataSource(tableNum(TableB));
qbds2.relations(true);
```

and launch the query ,
work well,

enjoy!